# ¿Como puedo hacer la conexion a la base de datos localmente con react +vite + electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

Resulta que estamos creando una aplicación de escritorito con react + vite y para trabajar en escritorio con electron pero tenemos la duda de como hacer la conexion con xampp y mysql para trabajar localmente o que otra manera puedo hacerlo

Comment: A Xampp no te conectas, es un manejador de instaladores... querras conectarte a un mysql? en ese caso, como conectarias node a una base de datos?

Comment: si la data es local y sólo la usa la app podes usar localstorage, indexedb, websql, o un sqlite ( hay varios packages para abstraer ese layer si despues necesitas cambiar el dónde se guardan las cosas ). si la data es compartida es el mismo flow de conectarse a un mysql remoto/red local

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.